# From what series is this brick? Duplo machine piece with yellow button, copyright 2007

Tags: part-identification, duplo, electronics

We have ten of these, but I don't know from which series! When pressing the yellow button it makes a sound that could be a train or a tractor or something like that. We are curious. Does anyone know?

[image: Front of the item]

[image: Back of the item]

Comment: It doesn't look like any Lego piece I've ever seen. Does it have Lego written on it anywhere? Are there any numbers written on it? Any other angles?

Comment: I have updated the question with more info on the sounds it makes, and with an image of the back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [Duplo Sound Effects Brick 2 x 4 with Water and Pump Sounds (Set 5605)](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61088c01&name=Duplo%20Sound%20Effects%20Brick%202%20x%204%20with%20Water%20and%20Pump%20Sounds%20(Set%205605)&category=%5BDuplo%5D#T=C&C=86)  brick from 2008. It featured only in 1 set, [5605 Tanker Truck](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=5605-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D).

[image]